# Blacklist and whitelist of domains on Debian Linux router

Tags: linux, router, blacklist, whitelist

I have to create blacklist and whitelist in small office for two groups of employees.

I divided the users into two group:

First group has block all webpages except about 80 domains which i want to add to whitelist. They have ip address 10.10.10.100-150

Second group has access to all webpages except few domains added to blacklist. They have ip 10.10.10.2-100.

My first thought about solutions was iptables. Two script (whitelist and balcklist) included to the main firewall.conf script but some domains can use more than one ip and some rules probably will fail in this way.

Can you give me a better solution to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

[Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) used as a proxy is your friend.